# How to minimize loop execution time in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute this code using for loop,

```
for i in fielding: # fielding has nearly 19000 records - dtype (list of dictionary)
   for j in player: # player has nearly 17000 records - dtype (list of dictionary)
       if i['id'] == j['id']:
          j['name'] = 'Luke'
```

So it takes longer time to run. Is there any alternative way to achieve this ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what data types are fielding, player are they list, tuple, or what?

Comment: List of dictionary

Comment: And what is supposed to happen with the outputs? Are you appending? Adding to something else? Or are you just wanting to update your dictionary?

Comment: No i am trying to update he dictionary.

Comment: But 'fielding' isn't a list of dictionaries, its just a dictionary correct?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: can you add sample data?

Comment: Is this the worst case scenario with a loop count of approx 300 millions (ie 19000*17000)?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Is it possible you could convert this to a pandas dataframe? One way to make this significantly faster would be to abandon the for loops altogether and do it in a vectorized fashion. You could always convert back to a dictionary at the end if you needed. If you provide an example of what one of your lists of dicts or dicts looks like that would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry i can't allowed to use pandas for this problem. Otherwise i would try that

Comment: Why, is it a school assignment?

Comment: yes.. Is there any alternatives works for dictionaries with pyhon?

Comment: Are you allowed to use python modules or just "plain" coding? Please update your question with further details that you are not allowed to use Pandas, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're trying to join data by an identifier (or any other fields). And that's the case when you may use `dict` or `set` to speedup id-lookups:

```py
# Build a set of ids you need to update
fielding_ids = {f['id'] for f in fielding}

# Or use dict if you will need to access the records
# fielding_ids = {f['id']: f for f in fielding}

# Update records with corresponding ids from the second list
for p in player:
    if p['id'] in fielding_ids:
        p['name'] = 'Luke'
```

Python `set()` and `dict()` are hashmap-based containers, which are optimized for almost instant key presence checks.

Comment: @saifislam, feel free to do a test with both solutions and compare the execution time.

Comment: I think it's pretty close to amortized `O(m+n)`, and there's no way to do it faster. Am I missing something?

Comment: I meant @saifs original loop compared to your solution (using 19000*17000)..